# PHP Curl post request not working no post

Tags: php, curl

It's not sending the post request. I am not sure as in why, or what I'm doing wrong.

This is the API in the database:

```
      //servapi added to code for clarity
      $servapi = "https://(hidingwebsiteforthispost).com/api.php?key=(my_key)&service=31&action=order&profile=[link]&amount=[amount]"

       //original code
        $arrayFind    = array(
            '[link]',
            '[amount]'
        );
        $arrayReplace = array(
            $link,
            $quanity
        );
        $APILink      = $servapi;
        $APILink      = str_replace($arrayFind, $arrayReplace, $APILink);
        $ch           = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $APILink);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

Added by moderator:

User is verifying whether a POST request is successful by reviewing his account on the destination server.  If successful, a new order will be started under his account.  When he uses the API string from requestmaker.com, a new order is created, but when he runs the above code, a new order is not created.

When using var_dump to inspect the returned packet from `curl_exec($ch)`, user states that the response is empty.

User has also updated his code to set CURLOPT_POST to true.

Comment: Vaxified L, in order to help the people who will answer your question, please add some detail.  How do you know the curl_exec() function is not sending data to the API?   Do you have logs from the server?  All the information you provide as to why you think the code is or is not working will help us to understand what you have tried and what you have not yet tried.

Comment: I do not own the API, but I have tested the request on requestmaker.com and it worked fine. But when i go to send the request on my server nothing happens.

Comment: So you are saying that the request should make a change that is visible on the target site, and when you view that site through another method that you do not see the change you were expecting.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, the API is supposed to start an order when the request is received, but when I do it on my server no order is started. When i send the request through requestmaker a order is started. - Hope this clarify's everything

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually doing a post request, you'll want to add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

in order to send a POST request.

See the [curl documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and specifically the [curl_setopt documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for more information.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Please specify what the result is after this change.

Comment: Nothing had really changed. I do not have/own the api so I do not have the logs for that. I receive no certain error on my server that is sending the request. Simply nothing happens when the request is sent.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @nvisser's suggestion, you should also capture and review the response from the curl request.  Change your `curl_exec` as follows:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Because you have set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to TRUE, your curl_exec encapsulates all responses as a string and returns them to a variable of your choice.

Output the response and you will likely find more information to help you diagnose the issue.

**Added after discussion in comments**:

Here is what we should do:

Since you do not have control over the network, try installing and activating the web server on your virtual private server so that you can receive and process requests at `http://localhost/fakeServer.php`

Once you have installed Apache2 or NGINX and set it up, create a small program called `fakeServer.php` at the root of that web directory, and set the API url to `http://localhost/fakeServer.php`.  Inside that script, make a log that outputs the content of the `$_POST` headers every time the script is run.

In this way, you can prove whether your script is sending out requests and what they look like to the receiving server.  This will help you debug your script to use the API class and verify that all *your* code is formatted well and operating correctly.

Have `fakeServer.php` output a response and check for that response in your program.  If all is working well, the output from `fakeServer.php` will end up in your `$response` variable.

If all is not working well, we have more control over the test environment to find the problem.

Comment: There is no response.

Comment: No response at all suggests that your internet packet is never making it to the remote server.  If you are testing your code on another server and your code is verified by that server, then you must break down the things that are different.  We can assume that your PHP is correct because you verified it on requestmaker.com.  Then think about your server and the network that it sits on. Is there a firewall that could be blocking your outbound requests?  If this is the case, then your request will never make it out until you find a way to get passed the firewall.

Comment: Try to think of the complete pathway that your internet packet will travel from creation to destruction and think about how that is different from the internet packet created at requestmaker.com.

Comment: Once that is done, look at the forums for the destination server.  In one case, I was building a Bitcoin trader, and the forum for BITFINEX noted that their servers only would respond to packets that had specific header values denoting the version of the API that I was using. Many other programers missed this, so there were a lot of posts saying "This does not work" with the recommended fix being "Add this version number to your Curl request header."

Comment: Also, if you let us know which API you are trying to implement, we may be able to help more.

Comment: I had tried a no-curl method and the request was sent, so I believe that the request are making it out.. Only reason i'm not using that method is cause the way I want to implement the API can not be implemented using the no-curl method.

Comment: Also here is the official API for the website I'm trying to use.. http://pasted.co/93b7b298 , i tried using it but it wouldn't work

Comment: So that class was written by the service, and you are just copying it into your code base, yes?

Comment: Yes, I copied the official API, replaced everything properly and still did not have any success.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the API class that they have written.  If you are changing the $api_url and $api_key appropriately, then we are back to network connection issues and not PHP coding issues.

Comment: Try using Wire Shark (free program) to verify that your computer is sending packets out.

Comment: Then look at your internet gateway, and try to access the firewall logs to verify that your packet is leaving your network.

Comment: I am using a VPS, from digitalocean. I have curl installed as well, just in case that comes up.

Comment: That does complicate things!  So your server is virtual. It exists on a network that is well maintained (we shall assume this), and that service expects you to be sending packets out from your virtual machine, so the firewall restrictions should be relaxed..... Hmmmm.....

Comment: Is there a way I may contact you, I want to explain some more, but I think it would be better off to explain things over somewhere else.. do you have skype, or anything?

Comment: That's okay.  I have to try to promote Stack Overflow sites before I offline a conversation.  Let me download Skype and open a chat window.  Give me a few minutes.

Comment: I edited the API, but sadly, same error as before.. Not sending anything.. My guess is because the URL has ?key=8888 and by default curl add's on ?object= not &object=.. If you know what I mean..

Comment: My skype id is jared.r.clemence

Comment: I had added you